# Export DataGrid to text file

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, text-files

I'm new to programming (1st year of learning at college) and I'm working on a small application.

I have a window where user can retrieve data from SQL to `DataGrid` and a `Button` for exporting some data from a `DataGrid` data to a text file.

This is the code I've used to get data from SQL:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server = localhost;Database = autoser; Integrated Security = true");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("selectproduct", con); // Using a Store Procedure.
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
DataTable dt = new DataTable("dtList");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", txtbarcode.Text);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
data.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapt.Fill(ds);
con.Close();
int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
if (count == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("This product doesn't excist");
    SystemSounds.Hand.Play();
}
else if (count == 1)
{
    lblinfo.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();

}
```

And this one is the code I used to write text file:

```
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("D:\\test.txt", true))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("Welcome");
        writer.WriteLine("E N T E R N E T");
    }

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("D:\\test.txt", true))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(data.Items);
    }


    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("D:\\test.txt", true))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(data.Items);
    }
    // Append line to the file.
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("D:\\test.txt", true))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("---------------------------------------");
        writer.WriteLine("             Thank You!   ");
        writer.WriteLine("        " + DateTime.Now + "              ");
    }
}
```

When I Open the text file i get this data

```
Welcome
E N T E R N E T
System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection -   Why isn't show the data grid 
data

---------------------------------------
    Thank You   
    7/26/2018 12:38:37 PM
```

My question is: Where is my mistake that cause the data from the `DataGrid` to don't be showed in correct way?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are currently writing the default `ToString` implementation of `data.Items` object which in case is `System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection`, if you want to print each item then you need to iterate through each item and then print the required value

Comment: For storing a brunch of data in a file I will recomment serialising them to Xml or Json. This way your data will be correctly escaped and saving retrieving information will be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the sample code [here](http://www.fourthbottle.com/2015/08/write-datatable-to-text-file-using-csharp-.Net.html).  This will do what you want.

```
public static void WriteDataToFile(DataTable submittedDataTable, string submittedFilePath)
        {
            int i = 0;
            StreamWriter sw = null;

            sw = new StreamWriter(submittedFilePath, false);

            for (i = 0; i < submittedDataTable.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
            {

                sw.Write(submittedDataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName + ";");

            }
            sw.Write(submittedDataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName);
            sw.WriteLine();

            foreach (DataRow row in submittedDataTable.Rows)
            {
                object[] array = row.ItemArray;

                for (i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    sw.Write(array[i].ToString() + ";");
                }
                sw.Write(array[i].ToString());
                sw.WriteLine();

            }

            sw.Close();
        }
```

Also, take a look at this.

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StreamWriter swExtLogFile = new StreamWriter("D:/Log/log.txt",true);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           //Adding data To DataTable
            dt.Columns.Add("ID");
            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("Address");
            dt.Rows.Add(1, "venki","Chennai");
            dt.Rows.Add(2, "Hanu","London");
            dt.Rows.Add(3, "john","Swiss");

            int i;
            swExtLogFile.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {  
                object[] array = row.ItemArray;
                for (i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                   swExtLogFile.Write(array[i].ToString() + " | ");
                }
                swExtLogFile.WriteLine(array[i].ToString());             
            }
            swExtLogFile.Write("*****END OF DATA****"+DateTime.Now.ToString());
            swExtLogFile.Flush();
            swExtLogFile.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you could have also referenced the [page where you have the code from](http://www.fourthbottle.com/2015/08/write-datatable-to-text-file-using-csharp-.Net.html) if you simply copy paste the stuff.....

Comment: Thanks to everyone :)

Answer (score 3):

You are using currently the following overload of the `WriteLine` method:

`public virtual void WriteLine(object value)`

If you look at the documentation of [StreamWriter.WriteLine(object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zcc928k(v=vs.110).aspx) it says that it:

> Writes the text representation of an object by calling the `ToString` method on that object, followed by a line terminator to the text string or stream.

This is the reason why you get the following nice line in your file:

> `System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection`

The documentation of [Object.ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) method reveals that the

> default implementations of the Object.ToString method return the fully qualified name of the object's type.

You would need to iterate through the collection and write each entry separately into the file. I would also suggest to use directly the data source instead of writing from the `DataGrid`.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{  
    object[] array = row.ItemArray;
    writer.WriteLine(string.Join(" | ", array));        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because `data.Items` is an `ItemCollection` and not a string.

All objects return the output of their `ToString` method when are asked to represent their contents as string. Normally you would `override` this method but in this case you can't.

So you need to tell the compiler how to retrieve the representative information from that collection. You can use either of these queries to fetch desired information out of the data grid:

```
var items = data.Items.AsQueryable().Cast<MyItemDataType>().Select(x => x.MyProperty);

var items = data.ItemsSource.Cast<MyItemDataType>().Select(x => x.MyProperty);

var items = data.Items.SourceCollection.AsQueryable().Cast<MyItemDataType>().Select(x => x.MyProperty);
```

`items` is a collection so you need to convert it to a string:

```
var text = items.Aggregate((x,y)=> x+", "+y);
```

`MyItemDataType` differs in each query and you have to find out yourself which data type is being used and `MyProperty` is the property in that class which represents the text of a row.

### Edit

You can use this code too. It does the same thing:

```
string text = "";
for (int i = 0; i < data.Items.Count; i++)
{
    text += data.Items[i].ToString();

    if(i < data.Items.Count - 1)
        text += ", ";
}
writer.WriteLine(text);
```

But pay attention to the data type of each item in `data.Items[i].ToString()`. For example if each item is of type `int` then `data.Items[i].ToString()` returns a string representing the value of that integer (e.g. 1 turns into "1") but if they are of other types (e.g. such as `Customer` or `MyDataGridItem`) you need to override `ToString()` method of that class to look something like this:

```
public class Customer{
    //...

    public override string ToString(){
        return this.Id + " " + this.Name;
    }
}
```

so if you cannot override this method for any reason you need to do the other approach:

```
string text = "";
for (int i = 0; i < data.Items.Count; i++)
{
    Customer customer = data.Items[i] as Customer;//cast is required since type of Items[i] is object
    text += (customer.Id + " " + customer.Name);

    if(i < data.Items.Count - 1)
        text += ", ";
}
writer.WriteLine(text);
```

furthermore, you can use a `StringBuilder` to speed up the string concatenation because `+=` is slow on strings.

Comment: may anyone of  you give a practical example. Because as i said i am new to this field, and i don't understand complex codes for beginning. Thanks again

Comment: Mong Zhu's answer explains the theory and I tried to elaborate using a practical example which you can copy/paste into your code. you can study more about these queries I posted using keywork `Linq`. However I try to post some simpler examples also.

Comment: I also have a question. With the above code how can i write the specific columns

Comment: @portal in the last piece of code, you can replace `text += (customer.Id + " " + customer.Name);` with `text += (customer.YourSpecificColumn);`. or you can replace `MyProperty` in the first three examples with your specific column.